# Is there a better way to refer to a future reader of a literary work?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a less bland way of referring to "future readers" of text?

> Enigmadan asked a question today (December 11th, 2014 for [future readers])
>
> ---
>
> If there are ever any [future readers] of this book I will be very happy.
>
> ---
>
> Enigmadan used a cd to store his music. For [future readers], a cd is a small circular device that was once used for storing digital information.

Comment: Did you really mean to say 'blasé'? I assume it's not exactly what you meant (because it doesn't appear to fit the context of your question), but that leaves me unsure regarding what you actually *did* mean.

Comment: @ErikKowal I thought I meant to say blasé. I guess I simply meant "bland". I'm looking for a more exciting or simply less bland way of referring to future readers.

Comment: All readers are future readers.  Just leave off the "future" part.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you want to show that the readers are in future compared with you.

Because they always will be present readers when reading the document, of course.

So I think you can use "later readers", "later lectors", "tomorrow readers" to show a comparison with your time.